# Image gallery where thumbnails always stay the full width of the div they are in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to make an image gallery, and I want to make it so the images, when the window is resized, will start to fall down one by one. But I also want it so that one wont just fall leaving an empty space where it was. Here is an example of what I am talking about. I want my images to behave in the way of this site. I am fairly new to this so I am not sure if that is something I can simply accomplish with css or html or even a plugin, or if that is just how the gallery this certain person used reacts.

http://justinmaller.com/

Comment: You need to study about responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for your responsive image gallery.